# ¿Cómo subir un archivo csv, con columnas masivas de registros masivos en php?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, csv

Tengo un archivo con 55 columnas, son aproximadamente 2500 registros en el archivo csv. No sé si haya un algoritmo para esto, yo intente crear un `array` con los nombres de los registros, y los inserte uno por uno, pero me da un error, y tarda mucho. En la actualidad realizo este procedimiento subiendo el archivo por `phpmyadmin`, es muy rápido ¿alguien sabe algo sobre como esta creado `phpmyadmin` para subir los archivos con eficacia y rapidez?

EL VERDADERO PROBLEMA aquí es que hay un `internal server` error, ya que son demasiados registros y quisiera saber si hay una forma óptima de insertar a la base con registros masivos.

```
 $cabezal = array("Telefono","DTO","siglas","Nombre"/*más nombres de columnas (hasta 55)*/);
if ($_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0) {
   $csv = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];

   $handle = fopen($csv,'r');
   $i = 0;
   while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,0,",","'")){

    if ($data[0]) { 

       funcion_importar($cabezal[$i]/*nombre de columna*/,data[$i]/*valor*/)

    }

}
```

Comment: Si pudieras poner un ejemplo del csv (no hace falta que sea con datos reales) y del código que has intentado y va lento, podríamos mirarlo para ver si hay algo que pudiera ayudar con la eficiencia.

Comment: Hola, este es un claro ejemplo de un solo registro en mi csv
,3875152836,ZAP0023,PANCHO ALIAS EL CHONCHON,REFORMA,CDA MAXIMILIANO HAMBURGO,AS,ASENICO,,,CDA,ZAMORA,,100,,EMILIO ZAPATA,MARIA,,CT BERNARDO,ASENICO,TELMEX,04/25/2014,MARZO,,,,,,,,,,Sin adeudo,,,,,,,,,,,AS

Comment: Prueba con esta web:
[http://file2sql.com](http://file2sql.com?utm_source=es.stackoverflow&utm_medium=reply&utm_campaign=csv_mysql) A partir de un fichero csv detecta tipos de datos y retorna un script mysql que crea y llena la tabla.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Para lograr resolver el problema de los datos masivos, los almacené en un array y los concatené en la sentencia (sé que no es práctico y peligroso, pero al menos en mi sistema se tiene que estar logeado para acceder a esta función) bien, el siguiente problema al que me enfrento es el 'internal server error' que hasta donde sé, éste se produce porque el tiempo de espera del servidor termina, y se modifica con las variables de php.ini que se llamaban me parece algo como time_max_exec aunque no recuerdo su nombre bien se que el problema proviene de ahí.

Comment: Deberías considerar en eligir una respuesta por el esfuerzo que aportaron Shaz, Jose Javier Segura, sí ninguno acertó a la pregunta por lo menos considerar a la respuesta que conllevo a resolverla.

Answer (score 3):

Para crear un arreglo (array) asociativo a partir de csv, puedes usar este código, el cual también utilizará la primera línea como las "keys" del arreglo generado.

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file));

array_walk($csv, function(&$a) use ($csv) {
  $a = array_combine($csv[0], $a);
});

array_shift($csv); // eliminar primera línea
```

Este código lo he utilizado con archivos csv de aproximadamente 1 millón de líneas y unas 30 columnas, con tiempos de procesamiento inferiores a 1-2 segundos, en PHP7.

---

Una opción más sencilla y rápida es la combinación `array_map` con `str_getcsv` para generar un arreglo no asociativo:

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('archivo.csv'));
```

Comment: gracias, pero no responde mi pregunta :/

Comment: Creo que @Shaz sí responde a tu pregunta. En mi opinión para archivos grandes puede ser mejor [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) ya que recorre línea a línea el fichero en lugar de cargarlo entero en memoria (en la documentación de ésta función tienes ejemplos de código bastante completos). Si lo que quieres es el código de phpMyAdmin puedes descargarlo en http://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/ y revisarlo cuanto gustes.

Comment: lo probé pero aún tengo problemas

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que sale? ¿Qué no leí bien? Si no entendemos es probablemente porque no explicas bien tu problema.

Comment: @JosePachDelgado no puedes decir que alguien "lea bien". Quizás si explicaras cuál es el nuevo problema que tienes te entenderíamos mejor.

Comment: se están fijando más en el código que en la pregunta:"¿alguien sabe algo sobre como esta creado phpmyadmin para subir los archivos con eficacia y rapidez?" y lo digo porque el usuario de que ha respondido abajo tiene una idea más clara del problema

Comment: Hay una pregunta en el título y otra en el contenido. Mi respuesta intenta resolver el problema general, el cual corresponde más al título de la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Yo uso esta función para importar datos desde un CSV, aunque lo mio es mas facil, porque son apenas 8 columnas

```
        $nombre_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
        $tipo_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
        $tamano_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
        $archivo=$_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];

        header("Location: ../partidos/partidos.php");

        if ($nombre_archivo!="")
        {

            $file = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
            $res = explode(".", $nombre_archivo);
            $extension = $res[count($res)-1];
            $nombre= date("YmdHis")."." . $extension;
            $dirtemp = "../../upload/temp/".$nombre."";

            copy($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $dirtemp);

            $row = 0; 
            $fp = fopen ($dirtemp,"r"); 
            //el valor mil indica la cantidad de bytes del archivo
            //si el archivo es un poco grande es mejor dejarlo en 0
            //en algunos casos el ";" no es aceptado usa ","
            $i=0;
            while ($data = fgetcsv ($fp, 0, ";")) 
            { 
                $local=$data[0];
                $visitante=$data[1];
                $resultado=$data[2];
                $fecha=cambiaf_a_mysql($data[3]);
                $hora=$data[4];
                $temporada=$data[5];
                $competicion=$data[6];
                $jornada=$data[7];
                $idequipo=$data[8];
                $pabellon=$data[9];
                $direccion=$data[10];

                $campos="local,visitante,rtdo,fecha,hora,temporada,competicion,ronda,idequipo,pabellon,direccion";
                $valores= $local . "|" . $visitante . "|". $resultado ."|" . $fecha . "|" . $hora . "|" . $temporada ."|". $competicion . "|" . $jornada . "|". $idequipo . "|" . $pabellon . "|" . $direccion ;
                insertarBD( $prefijo."partidos", $campos, $valores);
            } 
            fclose ($fp); 
            unlink($dirtemp);
        }
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, ya lo logre resolver :)

Comment: @Jose Pach Delgado, si alguna de las respuestas te ha servido marcala como aceptada, para otra gente que pueda tener el problema. Sino, pon tu respuesta para lo mismo. Un saludo

Comment: Buen punto gracias, lo haré